# How does RSpec's expect... to change... to... work internally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In RSpec, there is matcher `expect{}.to change{}.to` like

```
expect{employee.change_name}.to change{employee.name}.to "Mike"
```

It is very easy to read, but is not that easy to understand how it works from language standpoint. I suppose that `expect`, `to` and `change` are methods, but what objects are they called at? What curly braces mean in that case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` and `expect` are methods of `self` and `to` is a method of the result of executing `change` and `expect`. The `{}` expressions are blocks passed to `change` and `expect`.

The following illustrates the order of evaluation:

```
def self.to1(arg)
  puts "to1(#{arg})"
  "to1"
end

def self.to2(arg)
  puts "to2(#{arg})"
  "to2"
end

def self.expect
  puts "expect"
  yield
  self
end

def self.change
  puts "change"
  yield
  self
end

expect{puts "b1"}.to1 change{puts "b2"}.to2 "#{puts 'Mike' ; 'Mike'}"
```

which produces the following output:

```
expect
b1
change
b2
Mike
to2(Mike)
to1(to2)
 => "to1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a profound answer, @Peter Alfvin!

Answer (score 1):

They are `blocks` in ruby.

Basically the first step towards lambda expressions, basically anonymous functions.